# Plot incoming stream of numbers with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot an incoming stream of numbers as a real-time graph. currently, all it does, is to show a gray figure-window with no content. The data gets printed to the terminal as I expect it.

```
import socket
import matplotlib as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis([0,10,0,1])
plt.ion()


samples = 15*200

channels = [np.linspace(start= 0, stop = 0,num = samples)]

def animate():
    plt.plot(range(0,samples),channels[0])
    plt.draw()


UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 8888
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

k = 0
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(2048) # buffer size is 1024 bytes      
    # write data to channel
    channels[0][k % samples] = eval(data)[0]
    animate()
    print channels[0][k % samples]
```

Comment: Why bind `channels` to a list of a single list? Remove the `[ ]` around `np.linspace` and remove the `[0]` on each reference for cleaner code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `plt.draw()` by `plt.pause(t)`, with `t` being the time to wait between frames (it should not be 0). This ensures that the figure actually gets time to update and the GUI can process any events.

Answer (score 1):

Does it resolve the problem if instead of `plt.draw()`, you call `fig.canvas.draw()`? The method for updating belongs to the canvas object. Using the state-based interface of pyplot makes it less clear which object is being referenced, and you might prefer the OO interface. Especially because you are retaining the reference to `fig`, you might as well call it explicitly.

Comment: `plt.draw()` does the same as `plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()`; hence if one doesn't work, the other wouldn't either. If you are interested in a solution, read my answer.

Comment: OP marked solved. so must be ImportanceOfBeingEarnest. But I don't think those calls are quite the same and could be useful for troubleshooting. The OP assigns the disred Figure object to `fig`, and calling its `draw` method is conceivably different than `plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle`. Maybe OP has intervening code setting the current figure to something else. Maybe the backend being used by OP is not calling `draw` because the UI state is not idle for some reason. https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.draw_idle

Comment: `plt.draw()` does the same as `plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()`. `fig.canvas.draw()` is different, as it does not draw the current figure, but the figure `fig`. But since there is only one figure in the code, this is then again the same.